# Rare, but crucial issue with my Poker hand evaluator

Tags: java, probability, poker, weighted-average

I am writing an AI to play 5 card Poker. In this version of Poker comes a point where a player is allowed to discard none, one, two or three of the cards in their hand and replace them with random ones from the deck.

**EVALUATING A HAND**

My AI can give a unique value to any possible poker hand, and this value also corresponds to how "good" the hand is - a higher valued hand will always beat a lower valued one. To do so, the hand is firstly sorted in terms of "most important" cards first, and "least" important last.

e.g.

Two Pair: 7C 7S 4H 4D AS

Straight: 9D 8C 7S 6D 5H

Full House: 2C 2D 2H 7S 7D

Each type of hand is also given a value corresponding to how good this hand type is:

Royal Flush = 9, Straight Flush = 8, ... ,Two Pair = 2, One Pair = 1, High Card = 0

Now, using these sorted hand, as well as its value, a unique hex value is computed for the hand. The hand type value is placed in the most significant position, and then each of the 5 cards values (minus 2) are placed in the order that the hand is sorted. These six hex digits are then concatenated to give the final hand value.

For example, a Royal Flush (AH KH QH JH 10H) would have its vale computed as such:

```
         1st Digit      2nd Digit      3rd Digit      4th Digit      5th Digit      6th Digit
         HAND VALUE     BEST CARD      NEXT BEST      ...            ...            Worst Card

Decimal: RoyalF=9       A=14-2=12      K=13-2=11      Q=12-2=10      J=11-2=9       10=10-2=8
Hex:     9              C              B              A              9              8

-> Value = 9CBA98 ( = 10,271,384)
```

**DISCARDING CARDS**

My AI can now use these values to make decisions on how many, if any, cards to discard. Because of the way the hand is ordered, the cards to be discarded will always be the last card alone, the last two cards, or else the last 3 cards. A lot of work goes into this ordering of cards to ensure that the "least important" cards are last (for example, a broken straight JC 8H 7D 6S 5H would be reordered as 8H 7D 6S 5H JC, to ensure that the JC would be discarded, in the hope of completing the straight.

Next, my AI computes and stores all the possible hands that could be created by replacing the last 1, 2 or 3 cards with every possible combination of cards left in the deck (assuming, for now, that there are still 47 left). It can then compute the unique value for each of these possible hands. In terms of deciding what number of cards to discard, what I have done is simply computed the average hand values across the 3 groups of possible hands that could be achieved when discarding 1, 2, or 3 cards. Whichever of these has the highest average value (highest expected gain), it discards that number of cards, otherwise, if all 3 average values are less than the current hand value, it does not discard any cards.

**THE ISSUE**

For the most part, this works as I could have hoped. However, there are some rare cases where it does not work, and an average value lower than the value of the current hand is computed, yet, it would still be worth the risk to discard some of the cards.

An example of one of these hands is:

AH KD KS JC 10S

This hand is a broken straight, and so it is reordered as:

AH KD JC 10S KS

As of now, this hand is just a Pair, however, it is most certainly worth attempting to discard one of the Kings in the hope of getting a Queen and completing the Ace high Straight.

Despite this, when the average value is computed across all the hands possible whne discarding the King, it turns out to be a lower value than that of the current hand.

In order to overcome this, I was thinking along the lines of having the Hand Type Value (currently 9, 8, ... , 0) as a linearly/exponentially increasing function, thus the value of the hand type is increased as a factor of how good the hand is (perhaps powers of 2: 256, 128, ..., 4, 2, 1, 0).

This is just the first idea I have just brainstormed, so I do not know how well it would work. I am completely open to any other suggestions as to how this problem can be solved.

Comment: How do you determine if a broken straight should be ordered higher that a high pair, 2 pairs, a triple or the possibility of a broken full house?

Comment: Well you could never have a broken Straight that is also a Two pair, 3OAK, etc. So for the time being, if there is a broken Straight, it will always order the hand so that the "breaking card" is last. A broken Full House is either a 3OAK or a Two Pair, so again, this could never happen in the same hand as a broken Straight.

Comment: I should also add, that for the time being a broken Straight is just when the hand is one card away from a Straight. JS 9C 6H 5D 4C wouldn't be recognised as a broken straight, so it wouldn't be reordered with the J and 9 last.

Comment: _Never_ draw to an inside straight! Your scheme doesn't seem to be based on any standard analysis of poker probabilities.

Comment: Haha, it is just a college project, and I have never been actively into Poker, but upon just Googling "never draw to an inside straight", I see where you're coming from

Comment: Well then I guess the AI actually is calculating the probabilities better than I initially thought, as it always goes for an outside straight.

Comment: I think your AI is correct in this case. I have been playing poker for nearly 40 years, including a few as a pro. I have played a lot of 5-card draw. I can tell you with certainty that I would play the hand you show as a pair of kings, not as an inside straight--unless the betting structure were such that I could draw for free, perhaps. Of course I also usually draw one card to trips for deception--bet your AI can't do that. :-)